# Plugin for Javascript to interact with desktop window

Tags: javascript, gwt, desktop

I am looking for a way to give my gwt web application the ability to acces and send inputs to an open desktop window.

Basically it should just work similar to the java.awt.Robot class, being capable of analyzing the screen Data and sending (primarily mouse) inputs to either a specific window or any coordinate on the current Screen.

I was unable to find any common interface that does something like that, so I hope that I just oversaw something or somebody has an Idea how this can be achieved.

NOTE: I know that I could just convert the application to a Desktop variant, but I would prefer a more simple and less time-consuming solution.

Comment: I should hope that would never happen.

Comment: Oooh you came to my website, how about I open the file passwords.txt on your desktop for you!

Comment: I guess you got my point wrong... I am not looking for a tool to instantly access the Users desktop or remotely control his Computer remotely from the Script he downloads. What I need is a program on the Users machine that can interact with my web application, e.g. via accessing the browser content and performing an action in order to what it receives.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser is IE on Windows, you can use `ActiveX`. For other situations, you will have to develop your own plugin for each browser.

Comment: Thats what I feared. I still hope I'll find a way to solve my problem without having to create multiple plugins, but thanks anyway!